# Daterangepicker / Moment JS - Wrong timestamp

Tags: jquery, momentjs, daterangepicker, bootstrap-daterangepicker

I've been scratching my head over this for a while now. I am using daterangepicker.js (http://tamble.github.io/jquery-ui-daterangepicker/) in the front end of my UI. My implementation is pretty basic and can be found below. The issue is that whenever I convert the extensions time using moment.unix() the timestamp returns one hour before the date entered

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#date-range").daterangepicker({
        datepickerOptions : {
            numberOfMonths : 1,
        },
        presetRanges: [{
           text: 'Last 7 Days',
           dateStart: function(){return moment().subtract('days', 7)},
           dateEnd: function() { return moment() }
        },{
           text: 'Last 30 Days',
           dateStart: function(){return moment().subtract('days', 30)},
           dateEnd: function() { return moment() }
        },{
           text: 'Last 3 months',
           dateStart: function(){return moment().subtract('days', 90)},
           dateEnd: function() { return moment() }
        },{
           text: 'Last 6 months',
           dateStart: function(){return moment().subtract('days', 180)},
           dateEnd: function() { return moment() }
        },{
           text: 'This Year',
           dateStart: function(){return moment().startOf('year')},
           dateEnd: function() { return moment() }
        }],
        change:function(event, data){

            // gets inputted dates
            var inputData = $('#date-range').daterangepicker('getRange');

            console.log(inputData);

            // formats dates into unix time stamps
            var start = moment(inputData.start).unix();
            var end   = moment(inputData.end).unix();

            console.log(start);

            // get current URL of the page (without query string)
            var currentUrl = location.protocol+'//'+location.host+location.pathname;

            // create new url
            var newUrl = currentUrl+'?start='+start+'&end='+end;

            // redirect to new URL
            //window.location.href = newUrl;
        }
    });
</script>
```

An example out put is here: as you can see the start stamp passed to my moment js is Mon 2nd October 2017 at midnight (this is correct and reflects what I selected in the UI)

start: Mon Oct 02 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time) {}

When I use

```
var start = moment(inputData.start).unix();
```

It is converted to 1506898800 which reflects 10/01/2017 @ 11:00pm (UTC)

I have tried moment().utc().

Any pointers here ?

PS I am aware I could add 3600 to the timestamps but would prefer not to do it this way as I'm sure I am missing something relatively simple.

Thanks

Comment: Please note that `1506898800` is equal to `2017-10-01T23:00:00 UTC` that is same of `2017-10-02T00:00:00+0100` .

Comment: @VincenzoC How do I get moment JS to return this result. I have tried moment.local(). Is the only way to just add 3600 to the timestamp ?

Comment: Sorry, but I did not understand what is your expected result. If you want to parse your `inputData.start` as UTC use [`moment.utc`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/).

Comment: Hi @VincenzoC when the user selects start: Mon Oct 02 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time) {} in datepicker js. I would like the unix timestamp returned to reflect Mon 02 October rather than Sun 01 October @ 23:00. I have tried .utc as well but the date keeps returning as the 1st at 23:00

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `Mon Oct 02 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)` equals to 
`Sun Oct 01 2017 23:00:00 GMT+0000 (UTC)` when converted to UTC.

Seconds, .unix() will return the seconds from 1970 relative to **UTC time**. Timestamps don't have timezones.

The solution is fixing the time zone to a specified one, and by doing that using the most safe one (UTC, no DST switches). To do that, try including [moment-timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/) to the page and run this code once before initializing the datepicker:

```
moment.tz.setDefault("UTC");
```

This way all of your dates will be compatible with unix timestamps.